# url rewrite : more than one rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please Help to solve this problem

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 400 /tmp/error/404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404.html
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
#RewriteRule ^showthread.php?t=([0-9]+)/?$ /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 [NC]
```

all rules work but the comments rule i can't write it

can you help me to write this rule

**I want to redirect this path `/showthread.php?t=[0-9]` to `/vb/showthread.php?t=[0-9]`**

with out problems in seo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^showthread\.php /vb/showthread.php?t=%1 [NC]
```

Reference:  http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Note, per the example shown there as well, this will only work if `t` is the only parameter in the query string - but it could be expanded to allow for others as well, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)t=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^showthread\.php /vb/showthread.php?t=%1 [NC]
```

(I did just test this, and it seems to work without issue.)

Also, if you want this to redirect, rather than just proxying the request to the other php file, you'll want to add something like `[R=301]` to the end of the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: your answer work good , but can i use it without **RewriteCond**

Comment: No, you need the `RewriteCond`.  Per http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString, "RewriteRule cannot directly access the query string..."

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is, you have written ^showthread.php?t=([0-9]+)/?$ as regex. In regular expression **.**(dot) means anything can be. Try to change commented line with that,

```
RewriteRule ^showthread\.php?t=([0-9]+)/?$ /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 [NC]
```

Another thing is,

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This line takes all the requests directly and redirects to index.php. Because you said in regex that even it is empty, send the request to index.php again. Or maybe you have forgotten to put / (slash) before ? (question mark). Not putting that changes that regex's mean.

Comment: Don't we need to use `RewriteCond` to match against the query string?

Comment: By writing a regular expression in RewriteRule or RewriteCond, both of them can solve the problem.

Comment: Per http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString, "RewriteRule cannot directly access the query string..."

Comment: I have tried it now. Yes, RewriteRule didn't take query part. I have added RewriteCond and changed that 'showthread.php?t=$1' part with 'showthread.php?t=%1' then it worked.